# VScode C/C++ extension error when trying to assign a std::variant

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode with [Microsoft C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) to analyze this C++ code:

```cpp
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    variant<int, double> v;
    v = 12; //Marks as error 
    v = 12.0; //Marks as error
    //But compiles without errors.
}
```

The extension currently marks these lines as errors, but still can compile and run them with no problems.

To solve this, in `tasks.json` I added arguments like this:

```json
...
"command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "--std=c++17",
                "-pedantic-errors",
                ...
...
```

And in extension settings I explicitly set the C++ standard to `C++17` and restarted.

But I still can't get rid of the red squiggles.
On hover, the error says:

> no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::variant<int, double> = int

How do I fix this?

Edit:
In my previous question, the vscode just wouldn't compile. Now it does, thanks to the edit in the extension settings. However, I still can't get rid of the red squiggles.

Comment: did you change grammar check to your compiler, and did you set proper standard?

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki I only modified the standard to be C++17, everything else is default.

Comment: try to set: `Default: Intelli Sense Mode` in C/C++ Extension

Comment: Tried all options, none helped.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6623.

> It only repros when clang is used (not gcc or cl.exe), changing your compilerPath to g++ may be a workaround.